# Subtract number which was added before after some time interval of codes run but within processing time

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, signal-processing

I have an array of size (say `10`): example

```
A = [.80 .87 .79 .75 .49 .61 .63 .79 .67 .88 .40]
```

which I got after adding to an array

```
B = [.47 .05 .10 .29 .23 .14 .21 .29 .02 .10]
```

with an array of numbers

```
C = [.02 .18 .27 .14 .07 .08 .10 .17 .05 .027]
```

in a sequence to some random elements in each loop.

```
for i=1:10
  A = B(randomly selected array elements) + C(i);
end
```

But I have to subtract the number added in consecutive iteration after some iterations (example: the value of `C(1) = 0.02` and random array position selected was `([1 3 5 6 8 10])` I should subtract `0.02` in the array position of `([1 3 5 6 8 10])` of array `B`, lets say I am doing `10` iterations and the defined subtraction should start after 4th iteration.

Comment: is there any rule which could trigger the subtraction operation?

Comment: the subtraction should be in sequence C but at the same time we should also note the index of B where C was added during addition and the subtraction should start after 4 iterations of addition.

Answer (score 0):

```
indices = zeros (1,5) ; considering fixed number of indices in each iteration
for i=1:10
  ind_   = index of randomly selected items from array B;
  indices  = [indices ; ind_] ;
  A = B(ind_) + C(i);
  if (i == 4)
      A(indices(i-3,:)) = A(indices(i-3,:)) - C(i-3) ;
  end
end
```

Comment: indices should be randomly selected by us.
in those indices C(1) should be added.

similarly, select next indices

Comment: I did not understand. You have to write some code to select the indices randomly.

Comment: first iteration

indices should be randomly selected.
in those indices C(1) should be added.
 
A = B(indices) + C(1);

second Iteration

select new indices.
in new selected indices add C(2)
A will get updated.

A = A (indices) + C(2);

.
.
.
.

Fourth iteration

A = A(indices) - C(1);  ---> here indices are that selected during first iteration

fifth Iteration like first, sixth like fourth and goes on alternately.

Comment: Can you tell one more thing, number of indices are same from one iteration to other

Comment: The number of indices may differ in each iteration